# Replace image with JavaScript on timer

Tags: javascript, html

I am really new to JavaScript and working on a project to replace an image every 5 seconds without using a `onClick` command.

The first function `startAdPage` should start when the page loads, allowing the `setInterval` commands inside that function to begin. Once the `changeAd` function starts it is supposed to replace the image in the table with the matching id.

I would really appreciate some advice. Some that may be a problem which I am not sure about is I have the Javascript contained in the body of my document, but the onLoad at the start of the body. Is that an issue as well?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>CVR1</title>
</head>
<body onLoad="startAdPage()">
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
function startAdPage() {
 setInterval(changAd,5000);
}
function changeAd() { 
 //THIS NEEDS WORK should change the image every 5 seconds to replace the one in the table
 document.getElementById("adImage").src = images[index];
 index = (index + 1) % images.length;
}
/* ]]> */
</script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img id="adImage" src="pictures/cvb1.gif" ></td>
    <td><p>Advertisement</p><p>The Central Vally Realtors home page will be displayed in TEXTFIELD seconds.</p><p><a href="CVR2.html">Skip Advertisement</a></p></td> 
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how do you get data for images variable? is it undefined?

Comment: You never initialized `index` to `0`. And where is the definition of `images`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On this line:

```
setInterval(changAd,5000);
```

`changAd` should be `changeAd`

Remember to press F12 and check the console for errors, you have:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: changAd is not defined

As the comments show there also seem to be other essential parts missing: the `images` array and `index` is undefined.

```
var index = 0;

var images = [
    'image1.png',
    'image2.png'
];
```